# Can't find the "Create Manifest" button in the Artifacts dialog

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am trying to create a JAR file in IntelliJ but there is no "create manifest" button. How do I get the button to appear?

[image: Can't find the "create manifest" button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select "MapDataModel.jar" in "Output Layout" and you'll get "Create Manifest" button.

Comment: Thank you..! I didn't realize that the button only appears when the .jar file is selected.